# what is epsilon/k in epsilon greedy algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

As it was told it would choose the arm having highest emperical mean with probability 1-epsilon how did epsilon/k add to it (and also epsilon/k for random probability selection)in the equation written for probability in the page no:6 of the paper[Algorithms for multi armed bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6028.pdf).What does that mean epsilon/k writing there in the equation
[paper of "algorithms for multi armed bandit problems"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6028.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

We have:

- $k$ different arms/"actions" to select
- A probability of $\epsilon$ to select an arm uniformly at random
- A probability of $1 - \epsilon$ to straight up select the "best" arm according to our current value estimates (this is the arm corresponding to $i = \arg \max_{j = 1, \dots, K} \hat{\mu}_j(t)$).

The last point above tells you already where the "$1 - \epsilon$" term comes from. However, note that, when we decide to select an arm uniformly at random (which happens with probability $\epsilon$, the "best arm" again also gets another chance to get played. With probability $\epsilon$, each of the $k$ arms gets an equal probability to get played, which must then be $1 / k$.

So, in total, the "best arm" gets a probability of $1 - \epsilon + \epsilon / k$ to get played ($1 - \epsilon$ probability to get selected directly, and $\epsilon \times 1/k = \epsilon/k$ additional probability to get selected at random). Each of the remaining arms only has any chance of getting selected at all if we decide to explore instead of exploit with probability $\epsilon$, and in that event only gets a probability of $1/k$ to get randomly selected instead of any other arm, for a total probability of $\epsilon \times 1/k = \epsilon/k$.